# Python ascii hex conversion

Tags: python, hex, ascii, extended-ascii

I have a script written in python3 which reads data from a USB connected device.

The output from the device reads the following.

```
(240.0 08.3 240.0 50.0 08.3 2000 2000 24.0 25.0 21.0 29.2 27.0 1 10 030 0 2 1 1 01 0 0 25.0 0 1ÖZ
```

I need to validate this data with crc. The crc validation is, crc of all data expect the last 2 bytes should match the last two bytes.

Example: `crc(data[0:-2]) == data[-2:]`

I have the following code.

```
def validateResult(result):
    firstPart = result[0:-2].encode('utf-8')
    lastPart = result[-2:].encode('utf-8')
    crc = crc16.crc16xmodem(firstPart).to_bytes(2, 'big')
    print (result)                     # pints the input
    print (binascii.hexlify(crc))      # prints b'd65a' -> d6 is not in ascii table. While its in extended ascii
    print (binascii.hexlify(lastPart)) #prints b'c3965a'
    if(crc == lastPart):
        return True
    print ("CRC failure")
    return False
```

Code to read the data:

```
res += "".join([chr(i) for i in dev.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress, endpoint.wMaxPacketSize, timeout) if i != 0x00])
```

How can I correct this method so that it checks CRC correctly?

Comment: Trying to encode the raw binary data of the CRC into utf-8 is destroying it - it's not any form of text.  The data you read from the device ought to be a ``bytes`` object already, that you could just slice off the last two characters.

Comment: Did you mean the ".to_bytes(2, 'big')". Also, I have added my code to read the data.

Comment: No, I mean the ``.encode('utf-8')``.  Your read code looks unnecessarily complicated - doesn't ``dev.read()`` directly return a useful value?  You shouldn't need to loop over it.

Comment: One read returns 8 bytes of data. The entire message is from multiple such bytes. Also, all the '\00'(NULL) need to be filtered.

Comment: Filtering nulls is going to cause problems - a bit less than 1% of the time, your CRC will contain a null character.  Anyway, if you must do the read in that general way, use ``b""`` instead of ``""`` at the start, so that you get a bytes object instead of a Unicode string.